# Meaning of によって/により

Tags: grammar, translation, meaning, usage

I’ve come across this phrase によって/により quite often and I’ve researched and found these meanings: by Person (この本は君によって書かれた？); due to/ because of; by means of (The teacher checked their knowledge by the means of a test); depending on.

But I’ve realized that it has much more meanings? My japanese friend gave me these examples: 酒によっている, 
端によってください
So how do these translate into English and are there more uses for this によって/により or even によると (according to..)? I feel like Japanese people use this よる verb A Lot! Thank you in advance!!

Comment: You seem profoundly confused.  You are talking about 3 completely different verbs here with the false assumption that there is only one.

Comment: I know that they each have their own kanji, but I’ve been told that they are usually written in hiragana? And while talking I dont have these Kanji either way to seperate them, or am I wrong?

Comment: Writing them the same way doesn't make them the same word.  Consider the English noun *bear* and the English verb *bear*.  Both are written the same way, but that doesn't make them the same word.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the site! Great to see the community expanding!

I am also a newcomer, so apologies if I am wrong, but on this site you may want to be careful about using the word "research" too lightly (not saying that you did, but just in case...)

What I can say is that while 酒によっている　(=being drunk) was the only example with a "によって” that you gave,　"Xによると"　and "Xによって” mean the same (as long as X is a person / *source of news*),  "according to X" and in both cases the message (=what the source told) comes afterwards, i.e. the structure being SOURCEによると/によってMESSAGE

Comment: Hi @Tuomo, thank you for your answer. Why do I have to use the word research lightly??

Comment: ^ `Why do I have to use the word research lightly??` I think Tuomo meant to say you *shouldn't* use the word "research" lightly...

Comment: Oh yeah I got that haha, but whats so wrong about it? Is it because my research wasnt perfect in that sense?

Comment: Sorry english isnt my first language does research sound wrong in this case?

Comment: Hi @TrueHD, English isn't my first language, either, but if I was was worrying about whether the commas around the "either" above were neede, I would not do that on this forum but maybe in the "English Language & (its) Usage. And yes, to be picky to myself, I should also have used "site" instead of "forum" in my original answer).